# Why doesn't the extra C wire work when hooking up WiFi thermostat?

Tags: hvac

My existing thermostat has an extra 5th wire. It's blue. We used that as the C wire.  We have forced hot air so we checked the furnace and it has all the wires hooked into a clip that plugs in. It has switches designated for each wire. We turned the blue wire switch to the "on" position (it was off and all the others were on)and hooked up the blue wire to the C connector on the thermostat. Turned everything back on and no power to the thermostat.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the make and model of the furnace?

Comment: MAYTAG. NOT SURE OF THE MODEL. WILL HAVE TO OPEN IT UP TO SEE MODEL NUMBER. IT WAS INSTALLED IN 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Check the voltage between the R wire and C wire at the thermostat.  I bet it's 0.

It happens all the time... installers hook the wires backwards on the transformer.  Historically, it didn't matter because transformers make AC power. Polarity doesn't matter on AC.** As long as one side of the transformer went to "thermostat" and the other side went to "furnace", it was good.  The early transformers didn't even have R and C labels, that was added later as a "convention" for future expansion.  And the convention is "R" to thermostat, and "C" to furnace.

Well, these smart thermostats need power for themselves.  Since they're supposed to be getting "R", the instructions say connect "C".  Of course if your transformer is wired backwards, the terminal labeled "C" on the transformer already goes to the thermostat, so connecting another wire does nothing.

So on "C", what the smart thermostat is looking for is the side of the transformer which goes to the furnace (and not to the thermostat).  Whichever that may be.

** When I say polarity doesn't matter on AC, I mean for this little low-voltage stuff.  Different deal on 120/240VAC household power because they do certain tricks to improve safety.

Comment: Even if you swapped the legs from the transformer, wouldn't you still have 24v between `R` and `C`?

Comment: Of course, and that will work forever *if every installer is aware of the deviation from standard*.  That last bit being the issue; the smart thermostat revolution has brought an army of new installers who (quite reasonably) follow the labels rather than the wires.  Pros are more likely to read the wires because they know how and wire colors are easier to see than labels.

Comment: I'm just confused by the part where you talk about the transformer being wired backwards.  As long as one leg goes to `R` on the thermostat, and the other leg goes to `C` on the thermostat. Then it doesn't matter what color they are, or what the label says. So how can it be connected backwards?

Comment: The Nest will power up either way, but it will have trouble actuating the furnace if the Nest's R is the same transformer leg as the furnace expects on its C.   It will be sending the same voltage to the furnace that the furnace already has.